# Continuous Integration setup for ruby projects on linux server

Tags: ruby, linux, integration, continuous

I would like to use open source tools if possible.

here are 2 links I found but haven't tried them -

- http://pivots.pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/471-continuous-integration-in-a-box-exploring-tsttcpw
- http://laurentbois.com/category/continuous-integration/

Answer (score 6):

Try this CruiseControl.rb

http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/

CruiseControl.rb is written in Ruby and designed for ruby.

Another one is Hudson, it is built in Java, but it has a plugin for ruby

https://hudson.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 2):

Give Cinabox a try (I'm the author).  It is intended to make this as simple as possible, and uses cruisecontrol.rb.  There is a screencast and readme.  If you have problems, open a ticket using the LightHouse link in the readme.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is a lightweight CI server written in Sinatra called Integrity which you might want to take a look at. I mainly used it because it supports git.

[Git Reference](http://github.com/atmos/integrity/tree/master)